# Is there evidence that early humans hunted by running in packs over long distances to wear out their food?

Tags: physiology

As put forth by Christopher McDougall in the book [Born to Run](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307279189) (more recently in a [TED talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-iGZPtWXzE)) and a number of recent articles.

Comment: There is a 22 miles men vs horse marathon where men can win. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_versus_Horse_Marathon

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/can-trained-humans-run-faster-than-all-other-animals-on-a-marathon-distance

Answer (score 12):

Here's some interesting reading on the subject

**Results showing evidence in support of endurance running**

[Persistence Hunting by Modern Hunter-
Gatherers - Louis Liebenberg](http://www.canibaisereis.com/download/liebenberg-persistence-hunting-2006.pdf)

> The hunt takes place during the
>   hottest time of the day, with maximum
>   temperatures of about 39–42C. Before
>   starting, the hunters drink as much
>   water as they can. Then they run up to
>   the animal, which quickly flees, and
>   track its footprints at a running
>   pace. Meanwhile, the animal will have
>   stopped to rest in the shade. The
>   hunters must find the animal and chase
>   it before it has rested long enough.
>   This process is repeated until the
>   animal is run to exhaustion. The hunts
>   I observed involved three or four
>   hunters starting the hunt, even when
>   some of them were too old or not fit
>   enough to complete it. A team of
>   hunters can track much faster than one
>   individual on his own. In the
>   beginning the fittest runner may adopt
>   an easy pace while the other hunters
>   do most of the work tracking and
>   running. While tracking as fast as
>   possible, hunters are often slowed
>   down when they lose the trail and
>   struggle to find it again. When the
>   others drop out, the fittest runner
>   must pace himself to run down the
>   animal on his own.

You may also want to read the full [David R. Carrier article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2742907), but it may be behind a paywall.

**Research showing results against endurance running**

From the abstract of "[Bovid mortality profiles in paleoecological context falsify hypotheses of endurance running–hunting and passive scavenging by early Pleistocene hominins](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WPN-50XJBYJ-1&_user=2832433&_coverDate=11/30/2010&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1721902175&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000058902&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=2832433&md5=20cacbd81fbe3b758ef4d8e7fc34f7dd&searchtype=a)" Nov 2010

> The world’s first archaeological
>   traces from 2.6 million years ago (Ma)
>   at Gona, in Ethiopia, include
>   sharp-edged cutting tools and
>   cut-marked animal bones, which
>   indicate consumption of skeletal
>   muscle by early hominin butchers. From
>   that point, evidence of hominin
>   meat-eating becomes increasingly more
>   common throughout the Pleistocene
>   archaeological record. Thus, the
>   substantive debate about hominin
>   meat-eating now centers on mode(s) of
>   carcass resource acquisition. Two
>   prominent hypotheses suggest,
>   alternatively, (1) that early Homo
>   hunted ungulate prey by running them
>   to physiological failure and then
>   dispatching them, or (2) that early
>   Homo was relegated to passively
>   scavenging carcass residues abandoned
>   by carnivore predators. Various
>   paleontologically testable predictions
>   can be formulated for both hypotheses.
>   Here we test four predictions
>   concerning age-frequency distributions
>   for bovids that contributed carcass
>   remains to the 1.8 Ma. old FLK 22
>   Zinjanthropus (FLK Zinj, Olduvai
>   Gorge, Tanzania) fauna, which
>   zooarchaeological and taphonomic data
>   indicate was formed predominantly by
>   early Homo. **In all but one case, the
>   bovid mortality data from FLK Zinj
>   violate test predictions of the
>   endurance running-hunting and passive
>   scavenging hypotheses.** When combined
>   with other taphonomic data, these
>   results falsify both hypotheses, and
>   lead to the hypothesis that early Homo
>   operated successfully as an ambush
>   predator.

Bear in mind that this is targeting the very earliest humans, not necessary those that have evolved the necessary tracking and team working techniques required for endurance hunting.

Answer (score 3):

The paper [Why is alpha-actinin-3 deficiency so common in the general population? The evolution of athletic performance.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18637739), states in the abstract that a nonsense mutation to the gene ACTN3 that improves endurance activities has undergone strong positive selection in human evolutionary history. I'm not sure whether the paper states that the positive selection is as a result of the ability to wear out their food, though.

Declaration of interest: the people who worked on the paper were colleagues of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This article http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-24953910 describes how a group of four men in Kenia hunted down two cheetahs who kept killing their goats, over a distance of just four miles. After four miles the animals were so exhausted that they couldn't run anymore and were caught alive. So it's definitely possible.

Comment: Cheetahs are not endurance hunters - There is little reason to assume that they have better or as good endurance as common prey animals.

Comment: @Taemyr, I don't see where gnasher is making the claim that cheetahs are endurance hunters, merely that the Kenyan men successfully employed an endurance hunting strategy.

Comment: @BrianS He stats that using endurance hunting against a cheetah implies that it would be possible for humans to employ an endurance hunting strategy to gether food.  Since no one anywhere has cheetahs as a staple food this is fallacious.