# Can trained humans run faster than all other animals on a marathon distance?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, zoology, biophysics

During the athletics world championship, a commentator mentioned casually during the marathon discipline that humans are faster over long distances than all animals. 
I'm unsure if this can be said generally. Obviously some individuals cannot run, so consider the speed of the fastest individuals of each species.

Were there any scientific experiments performed to compare humans and animal? Alternatively, are there medical/biomechanical reasons upon which one can base this statement?

Additional research turned up the following [Nature abstract](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v432/n7015/full/nature03052.html):

> Here we assess how well humans perform at sustained long-distance
>   running, and review the physiological and anatomical bases of
>   endurance running capabilities in humans and other mammals. Judged by
>   several criteria, humans perform remarkably well at endurance running,
>   thanks to a diverse array of features, many of which leave traces in
>   the skeleton. The fossil evidence of these features suggests that
>   endurance running is a derived capability of the genus Homo,
>   originating about 2 million years ago, and may have been instrumental
>   in the evolution of the human body form.

Take this as proof that this question is trickier than it looks. The following articles also seem to support this theory: [Born to Run](http://naturalhistorymag.com/biomechanics/112078/born-to-run), [The Human Body Is Built for Distance](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/10/27/health/27well.html).

The **main factor seems to be temperature, which complicates an objective comparison of specific mammals**. Standard ambient temperature is from my knowledge around 25° C. It seems this a temperature where it gets tricky for horses and especially sled dogs to keep up with our best marathon runners. On even longer distances, likely even more. Probably a doubled marathon distance will already change the whole mammal endurance ranking. It would be interesting to see how desert/steppe animals like camel/antelope/cheetah do compared to dog/horse/human.

Comment: It is not even remotely true, unless you consider a human flying an F16. So if we will compare a human to ANY animal, over a long distance, then I'll pose a migrating bird as one counter example, most of whom travel far longer distances than any marathon. You did not state this had to be ground contact travel. Fish and aquatic mammals also move far faster than a human, over long distances. And if we do restrict this to ground travel, then you need to look at animals such as wolves, who have large hunting ranges, covering them in far shorter time than any human could.

Comment: ANY time ANY commentator tries to make humans unique in any way, I pretty much know they are just pulling stuff out of their butt.  ;)

Comment: As a true skeptic I'd be only satisfied with scientific experiment involving said commentator and a hungry cheetah.

Comment: @woodchips has **long-distance RUN** an ambiguous meaning to you? Neither birds nor fishs are running. Can a human run longer distance than a wolf on one day is a serious question from my point of view.

Comment: @Larian :) I generally dont take commentators too serious too or have my TV volume down, but **googling you find much non-scientific claims supporting this commentator statement** Do you think this is pure nonsense?! I mean from a evolutionary view, humans are the species spreading out regionally furthest. We are hiker, so there seems some truthiness in it :)

Comment: My statement still stands. Clearly a horse can outrun a human over any distance you wish to specify. As well, many carnivores are known to have large hunting ranges, far exceeding what a human can cover in the same time. This statement is as Larian says, merely that of a commentator making random noise. The human body is simply not optimized for the purpose of covering long distances in short times.

Comment: @woodchips sry im new to this site. But is this about personal convictions/belief or proving claims? Havent read so far the FAQ Your statement is as subjective as the commentators one, isnt it? Im not asking for personal beliefs here.

Comment: @Hauser: "has long-distance RUN an ambiguous meaning to you" There maybe some confusion here. The question was edited late to clarify that running was intended. The comment is now a little obsolete.

Comment: @woodchips: "Clearly a horse can outrun a human over any distance you wish to specify." I will take that bet! I specify a distance of 1m.

Comment: I am guessing that the commentator meant that through a diverse terrain.  A horse will be much slower in broken uneven terrain than a human who can use his hands and climb over areas the horse would need to go around.  Also a human can swim across rivers than horses would need to find a shallow crossing.  But for speed on packed well travelled land humans are likly not even close to horses, dogs, cattle, goats, or camels.

Comment: No kidding. No horse has made it to the Everest so far. P.S. comments are getting increasingly silly. You can rig the game ofcourse, but by any sensible "run" definition the statement is false.

Comment: [On wikipedia I found a link to the well known long-distance races](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naadam) in Mongolia, but no winning time. The distances for the oldest horses are 30km, and still below marathon distance. Now I'm searching for camel races.

Comment: [The camel seems to rescue the reputation of the animals.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_racing) 40 km/h for one hour means about the distance of a Marathon, but in half the time. Unfortunately, the Wiki text is deformed by a `citation needed` remark. :) We need definitively more Internet in the Arabian world, Mongolia and Africa (think: elephants).

Comment: @user thx, camel indeed seems most interesting comparison to me as i saw professional races with lightweight kids as rider and trained camels in Dakar afair. Humans should increase/redefine marathon distance to keep the lead :)

Comment: I heard about camel races on an IT-news ticker, because they use childs in the age of 3 years as jockey, which earned criticism from the western world. Now they try to replace them with robots.

Comment: I fail to see how a human can perform better than a horse with relative same amount of food and rest

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/is-there-evidence-that-early-humans-hunted-by-running-in-packs-over-long-distanc?rq=1

Comment: Top Arab horses have good endurance (better than ours) in a desert race (e.g. 200 km in 2 days) ... but they do that (as humans can) with brief stops for rehydration.

Comment: I think the biggest factor would be congnitive, not physical - why would any animal naturally develop the ability to sustain a maximum long-distance pace for over two hours of time? What would be the evolutionary advantage?  An predator that can sprint twice as fast for 20 seconds would catch, and delete such a development from future gene pools. Many other species might have the physical capability, but having the mental focus to sustain that pace for two hours, while metering the output to not run out of energy before that distance is covered is what would require a human-level of cognition.

Comment: So, a human rider, supplying that cognitive aspect is probably required, as any animal would not see the point.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet You seem to conflate sprint with run, and possibly other gaits. The phrase I've heard is like "humans can and did literally out run their prey. They would keep the prey moving, exhausting it before a sprint kill they could actually achieve." It sounds plenty plausible, evolutionarily. Most prey evolve sprint speed, leaving endurance ripe for advantage.

Comment: @fredsbend - No, I'm not, at all.  Two hours, at ANY pace represents a huge expenditure of energy. The fact that we don't have flesh-eating tortoises ruling any particular ecosystem as the apex predator would support the idea that an expenditure of energy for that period of time, especially for an uncertain outcome, would not be a trait that would give survival and propagation of the species advantages. How many fruitless pursuits at 60 or 90 minutes would go along with a successful one of 2 hours +?

Comment: This is a fantastic example of how a single word of difference can turn a completely correct claim (Trained humans can run faster/better than **most** other animals) into a completely false one (Trained humans can run faster/better than **all** other animals).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

We just need to look at [sled dogs](http://www.iditarod.com/learn/trivia.html) and do a little math.

> In 1986, Susan Butcher broke Rick Swenson’s record, set in 1981, by
>   completing the 1049+ miles in 11 days.

1049/11 = 95 miles per day.  This dwarfs a marathon, and marathon runners don't pull sleds.  However, there are other races where we manage 71ish miles per day.  This is for the [Self-Transcendence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Transcendence_3100_Mile_Race), which purports to be the longest foot race on the planet.  The Iditarod is in particularly cold climates.  There is a case of 100km being ran in 6:13.  100km is 62 miles, which starts to get into the Iditarod range.  [Someone also ran the AT, 2000ish miles in 50+ days](http://www.whereskarl.com/).  None of these accomplishments conquer the mile eating 95 miles per day that Iditarod champion dogs accomplish.

Most speculation I read is that the dogs outperform us only the in the cold.  However there's no comparable opportunity in warm climates (sledding requires snow, but if someone has an example, I'll include it.), so it is not clear that this is due to the dog being unable vs. humans not having a reason/method/desire to race dogs long distances in warmer climates.  Dogs can certainly handle warmer location in day to day living, for instance [Dingos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingo) exist across hot and [inhospitable areas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDingo-Distribution-Fleming.png), such as the [Simpson desert in Australia](http://www.outback-australia-travel-secrets.com/image-files/australian-deserts.jpg).

One reason that this is significant, is that it's contrived.  Humans are the only species to create physical challenges where people train for a large portion of their lives just to accomplish this purely contrived challenge.  The only animal I've been able to find that beats us is an animal we have harnessed to compete to the same end.  The comparison breaks down with most other animals, not because they aren't fast, but because it's not accurate to compare an olympic marathon runner with the average (as opposed to the best) kangaroo.  But it's not really possible (within ethical contrants) to find the "best" kanagaroo.  Yet even in this contrived contest, we are not the best.

If you compare the average human, we would fare less well, but that comparison is also harder to achieve, as we'd have to have numbers on what the average human can run.

The other animal that came to my mind is the ostrich.  Unfortunately all I have found so far is [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrich).  Still looking for more on this, however the cites look good so:

[People race Ostriches in Africa O.o](http://www.capetowntocairo.com/travelogue/riding-and-racing-ostriches-in-oudtshoorn-south-africa.htm)

> When being pursued by a predator, they have been known to reach speeds
>   in excess of 70 kilometres per hour (43 mph), and can maintain a
>   steady speed of 50 kilometres per hour (31 mph), which makes the
>   Ostrich the world's fastest two-legged animal.

These birds blow us away in both short and long distance running (we can't even come close to a sustained 31mph) and [they handle a 104 degree F range of temperature.](http://www.arubaostrichfarm.com/facts.html), which is not as great as ours, but is much above "cold only" climates.

Kind of makes me want to see an ostrich marathon :)

Comment: Is this for one sled dog (95 miles/day)? how about a human-horse comparison? I think there are horses trained for maximum endurance performance. Also if we couldnt order food via internet and had to "hunt" for food probably there would be much less "fatties" :) Kids get according to studies more and more unathletic the last decades. So yeah, average joe is probably in a pretty bad condition compared to average animal (not living in a zoo) but trained horses/sport-athletes look comparable to me.

Comment: Long-distance running is not inherently contrived.  For example, there are "persistence hunters" in Africa that run down an animal by tiring it out.  See eg http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUpo_mA5RP8 -- a human runner chases down a kudu over ~30km in two to five hours.  In this case, not being able to outrun a human over a marathon distance isn't contrived: it's life or death.

Comment: The intent is not to claim that all endurance running is contrived, but "let's go out and run for as long as I can run for no other reason than to prove I can run it" is certainly contrived.  30 kilometers in two to five hours is not like a marathon.  The top marathon time is about two hours and that's 42 kilometers.  The claim isn't "are humans faster than some animals over distance", the claim is that humans are faster than all animals over distance, and that claim is not true.

Comment: The Iditarod is a great example!  I was just reading a scientific article that claimed that non-human animals could run long distances only in cool conditions that lower the potential for hyperthermia.  It never occurred to me that this was one thing making the Iditarod possible.  Do you have other examples of fast distance runners in more temperate climates?

Comment: @russell I specified a bit more the question. Your answer is imo correct, but you could add or specify a bit the temperature/distance problem as this seem to be the crucial factors. Or we get the question how do humans vs. animals on 2xmarathon :) I think its ok when you simply mention a 2xmarathon can change drastically the ranking. Who is interested can use the links given here then.

Comment: @Hauser -- The entire topic is very speculative right now in the scientific community.  We *may* have evolved this or that for hunting, etc. etc.  I'm not comfortable making statements about sweat, temperature, etc., because while I'm sure I could find a peer-reviewed paper somewhere to support the opinion, I have not seen anything that convinces me of that position.  I respect your viewpoint on it, but I'd prefer to stick to what I can verify, and I can verify for certain that sled dogs outperform us :)

Comment: @russell im fine with this, but imho you should add then at least under which conditions (quote a temperature) they "outperform" us. At 25° C human seem to outperform sled dogs, so your answer might sound quite misleading. Under normal conditions the speed rankings seem pretty close (at least for human/horse) and some forum statements i saw state that dogs dont manage more than 10 miles with their jogging master...

Comment: [Here is ultramarathon, 100km in 6 hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultramarathon), even longer and faster races.

Comment: Two legs are supposedly more efficient. So I would restrict searches to kangaroos and ostriches (etc.) for long distance performance.

Comment: The material about the Iditarod doesn't seem responsive to the question. The question asks about a marathon distance, which is 26 miles. The Iditarod is 938 miles. The world record for a human in the marathon is just over 2 hours. For an apples-to-apples comparison, we would need to know whether athletically trained dogs can run 26 miles in less than 2 hours. The answer says that the dogs run 95 miles in a day. If they spend less than 7.3 hours running, then their pace is definitely faster than a world-record human running a marathon. But I suspect that they spend more time than that.

Comment: There was a report not too long ago about some villagers somewhere in Africa hunting down a cheetah that was killing their animals. They chased it for a few hours, and the animal was so exhausted, it couldn't even put up a fight when it was caught.

Comment: If roller-sledding ever becomes a thing, I would _love_ to watch it :D

Comment: I'm not sure why you're comparing marathons to multi-day races here. Humans can cover significantly longer distances than a Marathon per day, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Young_Australian_6-day_race for instance.

Answer (score 37):

**Short Answer** As other have noted, it's not true under all conditions. For example, sled dogs can outrun people easily in cold weather (see [DARPA studies](http://www.mattmetzgar.com/matt_metzgar/files/persistence_hunting.pdf)). However, it sounds like the commentator was referring to the [endurance running hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_running_hypothesis), which says ancient humans were able to hunt down nearly any animal by outrunning it. The context is key, because the hunter can start the chase in the mid-day heat of the African plains.

With that qualification, it's possible that humans can run down anything except dogs<sup>*</sup>. A [study](http://www.mattmetzgar.com/matt_metzgar/files/persistence_hunting.pdf) of tribesmen in Botswana concluded that this way of hunting, "produces a higher meat yield than hunting with bow and arrow, clubs and spears, or springhare probes and about the same as snaring. Only hunting with dogs produces a significantly higher meat yield."

**Background** The limiting factors in long-distance running are primarily oxygen intake and heat dissipation, both of which people excel at. One explanation, proposed in [this paper by David Carrier](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2742907) is that humans evolved to run long distances under the mid-day sun of the African savannah, hunting large game by chasing it to the point of heat stroke or exhaustion.

**Specialized Physiology** Our bodies are specialized to address the two limiting factors noted earlier:

1. Oxygen: Both humans and dogs have very fine (and easily damaged) lung tissue. This maximizes oxygen intake to support sustained energy output. Although many animals can sprint faster than a person, their lungs cannot supply enough oxygen to sustain those speeds. After a minute or so, when the muscles cells have depleted their internal energy stores, their output is limited by the supply of oxygen.
2. Heat: Even with enough oxygen, there's still the issue of overheating. People have two advantages here: Sweat glands (rare in the animal kingdom) and an upright posture, which exposes a very small surface area to the sun.

**Sources**:

- [Good overview, same the authors as Nature paper](http://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3716644/Lieberman_Marathon.pdf?sequence=3) (Free, full paper) "In short, for marathon-length distances, humans can outrun almost all other mammals and can sometimes outrun even horses, especially when  it  is hot."
- [Carrier paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2742907) (First page free) Probably the original source of the claim. "In spite of this, humans are adept endurance runners, capable of running down, for example, zebra and kangaroo."
- [Persistence Hunting by Modern Hunter-Gatherers](http://www.mattmetzgar.com/matt_metzgar/files/persistence_hunting.pdf) "Persistence hunting takes place during the hottest time of the day and involves chasing an animal until it is run to exhaustion."
- [Cite for Dogs beating humans](http://www.outsideonline.com/fitness/endurance-training/It-s-the-Dog-in-You.html) Magazine article about studies on sled dogs.

*By dogs, I mean Canidae, the family of animals including the domesticated dog, wolves, coyotes, etc.

Comment: Hey Konrad, thanks for your contribution, however I am afraid that the lack of sources makes your answer not very meaningful on this site. Can you look better and try to find confirmation? Otherwise you are just posting a similar (if opposite) claim, instead of clearing up what is going on here :-)

Comment: The German wikipedia talks about an average, daily distance of 22,1 km for female and 27,6 km for male wolfes. Yes, it is only the average, and probably more than what the average man performs, but a marathon runner absolves that distance in 1 to 1.5 h. [Wikipedia: Wolf(de)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf)

Comment: @user: an average can be misleading. How frequently do the wolves hunt? One 60 km hunt per three days, still could fit well within 27 km average. Still other info in the wikipedia seems to confirm what you write: " Wolves usually give up chases after 1–2 km, though one wolf was recorded to chase a deer for 21 km."

Comment: Konrad didn't mention any numbers in his post.

Comment: [Scientists find gene clue to athletic endurance](http://www.abc.net.au/news/stories/2007/09/10/2028247.htm?site=news) mentions that a gene mutation useful for endurance running has undergone strong positive selection. (Conflict of interest: I used to work with one of the researchers)

Comment: Also human endurance hunters carried water with them. I bet that really really helped.

Comment: Another advantage humans have over many other animals in terms of heat dissipation is a lack of fur, decreasing our overall insulation, and making the sweat much more effective

Comment: @KevinWells Insulated barriers work in both directions. On other words, fur works to keep heat out as much as it works to keep it in.

Comment: @fredsbend That is definitely not true in the situation we're talking about. If it was then why do mammals in cold climates tend to have dense fur where mammals in warm climates tend to have reduced or no fur? The key is that while fur keeps out the solar/environmental heat, it keeps in metabolic heat, which is a much more significant factor when you're talking about a high metabolic output situation like long distance running. Also as I said, not having fur allows sweat to be much more effective because it doesn't just dampen the fur, it is allowed to evaporate quickly

Comment: @KevinWells You're just giving the details of what I said. Fur insulates against outside heat transferring in. Depending on how animals cool their bodies, they may benefit greatly or only a little from this fact. Horses, which sweat a great deal, benefit greatly. Lions, which only pant, benefit less. Both still have fur.

Answer (score 34):

**No, horses run faster and longer.**

When comparing [marathon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon) and [endurance riding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_riding) we get the following numbers :

- Human : 42.195km in 2:03:38, average speed of 20.5km/h (world record at 2011 Berlin Marathon)
- Human : 160km in 11:28:03, average speed of 14km/h (100miles ultramarathon [world record](http://www.iau-ultramarathon.org/images/file/World_Best_Performances_Ocober_2010.pdf))
- Horse : 160km in 6:21:12, average speed of 25.2 km/h ([world record](http://www.endurance.net/international/UAE/2010PresidentsCup/) at 2010 President's Cup in Abu Dhabi, source: [FEI](http://search.fei.org/Search_Centre/Result/Pages/ResultList.aspx?p=858AEC8108C3B1F6322107237DB6800792985A264624613FEACE645A73BEF9B9))

Not to mention the horse carries a 75kg weight on his back. UAE are well known for their endurance rides. I don't see the time when we'll be able to run a marathon 25% faster than the current WR four times in a row...

FYI, we also learn that :

> Camels competed against horses in this 40-km pioneering event in the dunes of Dubai and the first 15 places were taken by horses. ([source](http://www.uaeequafed.ae/endhistory.htm))

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_versus_Horse_Marathon

Comment: I'm reading that a human ran for 11.5 hours, while the horse did 6:21. I don't think the claim is about speed (distance × time). "Endurance running" strongly implies time only. Obviously horses are faster and can cover more distance in X timeframe.

Comment: @fredsbend: the title of the Q suggests otherwise "Can trained humans run **faster** than all other animals on a marathon distance?"

Answer (score 14):

There is an [event in england](http://misterdavid.typepad.com/traditional_sports/2009/12/man-vs-horse.html) that is run every year:

> In 1980, in the mid-Wales town of Llanwrtyd Wells, an argument broke
>   out in the pub concerning an age-old matter.  “Yes, we all know that
>   horses can sprint fast,” one man declared, “but, over a real distance,
>   man is its equal.”  The pub was the Neuadd Arms and the speaker was
>   the landlord, Gordon Green.  To resolve the dispute, Green suggested a
>   full public test: a race.  A £1000 prize was put up to attract
>   competitors willing the attempt the feat, and the Man vs Horse
>   Marathon has been staged every year since.
>
> Still organised by creator Gordon Green, the Man vs Horse Marathon is
>   run over a rough, cross-country course of 22 miles, and has become the
>   largest horse race in Britain, attracting more riders in recent years
>   than the forty competitors in a Grand National.  Numbers of entrants
>   on the side of the runners now usually reach over two hundred and
>   fifty, and are also increasing.

<strike>Runners are given a 15 minute head start (A skilled runner can have over 2 miles down in that time some almost 3)   Dispite this</strike>

Runners start 15 minutes earlier than the horse riders but the event is a timed race.  So times are compared not who comes in earliest.

Here are the results from [2007](http://www.onlineraceresults.org.uk/mvh-full-07.htm)(the last time a human won) and [2012](http://www.onlineraceresults.org.uk/mvh-full-12.htm).  [The site](http://www.onlineraceresults.org.uk/) has other years but not all the Man v Horse results on a single easy to link page.

> Horses have had the upper hand on runners in all bar two of the races
>   to date.

So it is possible for a man to run faster than a horse over a marathon but not as the norm.  In 2012 the first 8 times were all horses.  Though the top human did beat several horses. It seems a good horse will beat a good human runner most of the time.

Comment: @Oddthinking: It's a timed race so the amount of headstart doesn't affect the final score; it's the time taken that counts.  The headstart is just to stop horses trampling humans at the start line!

Comment: @tynam - That comment was before my update and that was clarified.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the second part (and A.Rex's comment), [humans sweat a lot](http://www.physorg.com/news95954919.html). In addition, we're hairless and breathe through the mouth. This all helps to dump heat, which is one of the most limiting factors. [It's thought](http://discovermagazine.com/2006/may/tramps-like-us/article_view?b_start%3aint=1&-C=) this helped in scavenging (run to a carcass if you sport vultures, before they eat it) and later hunting.

If you eliminate heat as a factor, e.g. by [staging a run in Wales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_versus_Horse_Marathon), horses generally do better.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is actually a misstatement of something else that's true. Even then, it doesn't work against all running animals.

Humans are among the best [persistence hunters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_hunting) in nature. Persistence hunting is when you follow your prey at slow speed but never give up. ***Over a long enough distance humans will outrun/outwalk and catch any prey animal***. So far, there has not been a single species of prey animal that humans cannot catch up to (and yes, that includes horses).

The exception is when you compare us to other persistence hunters. African wild dogs may be better than us at persistence hunting. We may not be able to catch an African wild dog purely by persistence hunting (when the animal you chase give up and stop running before you do). We have to resort to ranged weapons (guns, spears) at the end.

Comment: Would you mind citing sources, particularly for the statement "Over a long enough distance humans will outrun/outwalk and catch any prey animal."? It would improve the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples given so far of animals outrunning humans over long distances, the animals have been human trained and controlled. The situation may be different if the animals are allowed to operate themselves.

It is widely reported that the San (Kalahari bushmen) [can outrun antelopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_hunting). They do it by having the animal run away from them, catching up with it before it has a chance to regain its breath, and continuing this until the antelope gives up. In a [test in New Mexico](http://www.outsideonline.com/outdoor-adventure/nature/Fair-Chase.html), marathon runners managed to get close enough to a pronghorn for a kill. Pronghorns are capable of more than 80 km/h over short distances and 50km/h over several km.

I will admit though that wolves will probably beat even the best humans, especially in snow. I can't see anyone volunteering to test it though!

Comment: I remember listening to ... umm... This American Life? where someone tried this with deer, and found they would mix in with other deer until he could no longer tell which deer was the one he selected  to run-down. Anecdotal, but interesting.

Comment: The same happened to the guys chasing the pronghorns. But I assume that the San, with many millennia of experience, would be able to distinguish their prey rather better.

Comment: Or just heave a clod into the herd and whichever one you wallop on its fleeing backside (leaving a mark) is the one you concentrate on thereafter.

Comment: Another example of men outrunning animals (horses): http://www.slate.com/articles/sports/sports_nut/2012/06/long_distance_running_and_evolution_why_humans_can_outrun_horses_but_can_t_jump_higher_than_cats_.html

Answer (score -2):

Distance record in a day for a human is 188.590 miles.[1]
I can't find any record of an attempt at more than 100 miles for a horse. This makes it very difficult to say which can run **further** in a comparison of human ultramarathon vs endurance riding, contrary to some of the other answers.
It's also not ideal to compare different races of the same distance across different terrain.
However, the question was with regard to a marathon distance which is 26.2 miles[2].
Some of the other answers have already pointed to the annual Man vs Horse marathon in Wales, which has only been won by a man twice out of thirty-three races.[3]
It has the advantage of comparing both man and horse on the course, on the same day. Given that fact, it's probably the fairest source of an answer to the question despite the fact that it actually falls approximately 4 miles short of being a true marathon.

Sources:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_run
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_versus_Horse_Marathon

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). I am trying to understand what your answer offers over other answers that you refer to. You can't find more than 100 miles for a horse, but someone else showed sled dogs can. You comment on not knowing who can run *further*, but the question was about *faster*. The Man v Horse race is discussed in more detail in other answers.

Comment: Actually, nobody clamed sled dogs could. The claim was 95 miles. So logically with the evidence we have, humans can potentially beat sled dogs and horses over distances in excess of 100 miles (completing it within a day while other animals can not).